# root file system mounts as read only after some time

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive, filesystem

My root (`/`) file system get remounted as read only after the system has been up for some time. This seems to vary from 3 hours to 48 hours. This system is running Ubuntu desktop 14.04. Its primary function is to run several Virtual Machines for myself. Here is the system config.

- Dell XPS 8700
- Intel i7 4770 24GB ram
- 128 GB mSATA SSD (this hold the
  `/` file system that has been giving me issues. It also contains swap
  and other system file systems)
- 3x 1TB SATA drive (no problem here) But they hold the VM files. This
  currently only runs 3 VMs.

A similar system (HP) has 32GB ram but same config otherwise does not have this issue. It runs 12 VMs no prob.

After `/` remounts as read only the VMs die as they write to a temp location on the SSD. I cannot `sudo` on the machine. And if I try to run the terminal command "mount" terminal just closes. After a reboot, I am asked to fix file system error (at startup) which I do and this works fine until the next incident.

I have backups of the VMs (plus their drives seem to be fine). But I would rather fix this installation than redo it since I have made changes that customize the system to my liking. Greping `dmesg` for EXT4-fs show this but I think this is just startup. No errors.

```
[    1.331446] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.474298] EXT4-fs (sde1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    2.584750] EXT4-fs (sda): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.637858] EXT4-fs (sdc): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.768738] EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.850718] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

I have run smart test in Disks. But it says everything is ok there. (And the machine is only 3 months old. This issue has been prominent for about 3 weeks now.

I'm open to ideas.

EDIT 1:
It crashed last night. So i did some digging.
charles@VMH2:/var/log$ cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep sde1

Jul 18 19:19:40 VMH2 kernel: [    0.892391]  sde: sde1 sde2 < sde5 >

Jul 18 19:19:40 VMH2 kernel: [    1.331446] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

Jul 18 19:19:40 VMH2 kernel: [    2.474298] EXT4-fs (sde1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072962] INFO: task jbd2/sde1-8:212 blocked for more than 120 seconds.

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072968] jbd2/sde1-8     D ffff88061ecd30c0     0   212      2 0x00000000

Jul 19 11:48:50 VMH2 kernel: [    0.888753]  sde: sde1 sde2 < sde5 >

Jul 19 11:48:50 VMH2 kernel: [    0.961088] EXT4-fs (sde1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

Jul 19 11:48:50 VMH2 kernel: [    1.999033] EXT4-fs (sde1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
charles@VMH2:/var/log$ cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep 27950

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072962] INFO: task jbd2/sde1-8:212 blocked for more than 120 seconds.

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072966]       Tainted: P           OE 3.16.0-43-generic #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072967] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072968] jbd2/sde1-8     D ffff88061ecd30c0     0   212      2 0x00000000

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072971]  ffff8805f8297cb0 0000000000000046 ffff8805f8218a30 ffff8805f8297fd8

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072973]  00000000000130c0 00000000000130c0 ffff8802e8570000 ffff8805f8297d98

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072975]  ffff8805f89160b8 ffff8805f8218a30 ffff8805dc2c9e00 ffff8805f8297d80

Jul 19 04:49:13 VMH2 kernel: [27950.072977] Call Trace:

It appears to me that
INFO: task jbd2/sde1-8:212 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
is the source of my issues. I just don't know what the message means (or anything after it). Does anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: Did you ever manage to resolve this? I'm having the same problem on a Dell laptop. And I have seen others with Dell laptops having this issue also http://askubuntu.com/questions/251284/ubuntu-goes-into-read-only-mode-randomly